# Microsoft avatar colors assignment

Tags: android, html, css, outlook, angular-material

How does Microsoft choose how to assign a color to a contact in a Microsoft application?

I've googled and I can't find any direction.

In Outlook or Android, when I add a new contact that doesn't have an image attached to its avatar, Microsoft automatically assigns a colored circle with the initials in it. I am building an application where this can be useful.

How does Microsoft achieve this? I mean, what's the logic behind it? Is it a color assigned to each initial in the alphabet? I think not, since in my contacts Leo and Laura have different colors. Conversely, Laura and Rick have the same colors.

Below is an image of some examples. Notice the inconsistency between colors across initials

[image]

Comment: Please, if you want to downvote, be my guest, but give a reason and a solution. For example "not appropriate for SO, post it in _____" And I will do so. Don't you think that is more productive that showing off your incredible powers to downvote lol Come on, let's help each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact colors in Outlook are randomized, this is done in User Interface and Human Computer Interaction projects because it breaks up the look of the interface and makes it easier to differentiate parts of the interface. The colors are random (and not based off initials) because if they were you may end up with a whole set of contacts with the same name (alphabetically or sort by use etc.) Nothing fancy about it. Google, Github and Stack Overflow do the same things with their avatars.

Hopefully this clears up your question. For more design philosophy, I'd look through the documents for Google Material and Windows Metro.

**Edit**: The randomization in Outlook is actually predictable, the color used seems to be derived from the info given. (At least the name given, the color isn't alphabetical but certainly influenced by the data input.) A quick test confirms it. By making exact contacts you produce the same colors. If you put both the first and last names in a single category you return the same color.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I think this can be as easy as a small array of colors and  math.random asigning the background color  to the avatar on user create. I built this one just a minute ago in codepen. http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/WpgMJX

Comment: If its correct you might want to check it as answered, this keeps it from cluttering unanswered questions. If your looking for a discussion we should move it to another part of the site.