# Microsoft Account Profile Icon: Change Color

Tags: windows, outlook, ms-word, ms-office

How do I change the color of Microsoft Account Name initials icon? I want to change to blue or green. I don't see the option here, https://account.microsoft.com/profile/

[image]

Research: This question [Microsoft avatar colors assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054393/microsoft-avatar-colors-assignment) is only for Microsoft contacts in outlook, looking to change my own icon :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook or Word extensibility model (object model) doesn't provide anything for that.